# emacs web-mode indent javascript not correct

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

web mode indent not correct when line too long.
the code:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    components: {

    },
    asyncData ({ params }) {

      return axios
        .get().then((res) => {
          return { title: res.data.title }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

The following is correct.

```
      return axios
        .get().then((res) => {
          return { title: res.data.title }
      })
```

but:

```
      return axios.get()
             .then((res) => {
          return { title: res.data.title }
      })
```

when i break line behind "axios", it's not correct

anybody help??

Answer (score 2):

Ah... I found it.

```
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-calls" . nil))
```